# Recaptcha formatting issue in ExpressJS/Jade

Tags: express, pug, recaptcha

I've plugged recaptcha into my ExpressJS app and it's working except the formatting includes extra <'s and >'s. I've followed instructors from here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/re-captcha but it is using EJS and not Jade.

[image: Why the >>'s?]

Code:

```
form(name='signupform', action='/signup', onsubmit='return validateSignupForm();', method='post')
        .form-group
            label First Name:
            input.form-control(type='text', name='first_name')
            label Email:
            input.form-control(type='text', name='email')
            label Password:
            input.form-control(type='password', name='password')
            label Password Again:
            input.form-control(type='password', name='password_again')
            br
            #{recaptcha_form}
          #alert
            if flash_message && flash_message.length
                div.alert.alert-danger
                    strong #{flash_message}
          button.btn.btn-warning.btn-lg(type='submit') Signup
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting issue by using an Unescaped Buffered Code.
(So in this example, I switched #{recaptcha_form} to != recaptcha_form as in https://github.com/mirhampt/node-recaptcha/blob/master/examples/views/form.jade

Comment: Just post that as an answer and accept it yourself so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the formatting issue by using an Unescaped Buffered Code.

So in this example, I switched #{recaptcha_form} to != recaptcha_form as in:
https://github.com/mirhampt/node-recaptcha/blob/master/examples/views/form.jade